# What is abrt and the process abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace?

Tags: fedora

I recently noticed a process I hadn't seen before called `abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace` that was churning on my laptop. I waited a bit and it never seemed to stop so I killed it.

#### Questions

- Did I just shoot myself in the foot somehow down the road?
- What was this process doing?
- Is there a way to spy on what this application is up to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Initial investigation

I checked to see what RPMs this application was a part of.

```
$ type -a abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace
abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace is /usr/bin/abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace
abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace is /bin/abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace

$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace /bin/abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.1.10-1.fc19.x86_64
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.1.10-1.fc19.x86_64
```

That package's description is as follows:

> This package contains hook for C/C++ crashed programs and abrt's C/C++

The RPM also mentions this URL: https://fedorahosted.org/abrt/. That URL takes you to a page that claims it's obsolete, directing you now to a GitHub page: https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/ABRT-Project.

#### ABRT

This is apparently a package for reporting problems.

> ABRT is a set of tools to help users detect and report problems. It's main purpose is to ease the process of reporting an issue and finding a solution.

It goes on to also describe it as follows:

> ABRT consists of a daemon that monitors logs, system crashes and triggers events based on the type of crash. Also provides desktop notification that popup at the time of a crash. The user can work with gnome-abrt, GUI that presents a list of crashes and available actions or abrt-cli, command line interface with similar functionality.

The overview page lists the following features of the ABRT daemon that it will automatically detect issues for, and automatically report logs back to "somewhere".

- C/C++ crashes
- generates backtrace automatically (installs debuginfo pkgs if necessary)
- identifies the crashing function
- unhandled Python exceptions
- kernel oopses (non critical)
- kernel crashes (critical, system crashes)
- XORG crashes (xorg doesn't crash like other C/C++ programs)
- Java exceptions (using JVMTI, still proof of concept, might have performance impact)

#### So what was it doing?

The overview page mentioned this path for ABRT, `/var/tmp/abrt`.

```
$ ls -l /var/tmp/abrt/
total 4536
-rw-------. 1 root root 13344768 Jan  9 19:32 abrt-applet-coredump
-rw-------. 1 root root       13 Jan 17 12:13 last-ccpp
-rw-------. 1 root root       15 Jan 13 17:13 last-via-server
```

The file for today, `last-ccpp` would be the likely candidate for what `abrt...` was up to. That file wasn't much help.

```
$ sudo more /var/tmp/abrt/last-ccpp
/usr/bin/bash
$
```

The overview page then showed a screenshot that I did recognize. So I think killing the `abrt...` process is not much of a risk at all.

[image: ss #1]

Comment: ... wait, that's not Fedora 19, that's RHEL7 beta.

Comment: @jsbillings - good catch, hadn't noticed the el7 at the end of the package's name in the screenshot. That's just a example dialog though, my conclusions are still apt. We all get those exact same dialogues in F19 too.