# Can I safely disable abrtd on CentOS 6?

Tags: daemon, init.d, centos

There is this nice new daemon called **abrtd** running on CentOS6.

This was inherited from upstream RHEL6. There this can be used (for instance) to automatically generate service-requests.

In an environment where we have `logwatch` and full monitoring of our servers active - is there any benefit in having this daemon up and running?

Comment: Related: [What is abrt and the process abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109799/what-is-abrt-and-the-process-abrt-action-generate-core-backtrace)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to run `abrtd`, no.  As per `man abrtd`:

> **abrtd** is a daemon that watches for application crashes. When a crash
>   occurs, it collects the problem data (core file, application’s command
>   line etc.) and takes action according to the type of application that
>   crashed and according to the configuration in the abrt.conf config
>   file.

The default is probably to try reporting it to Redhat (via HTTPS, I think, not email).  If you don't care about that at all, then there's no point in using it.  The daemon consumes almost no resources in any case.

Comment: Yes it makes HTTP(S) calls with failures. Fedora & CentOS both use this facility and it can be disabled.